# Не получается изменить размеры UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

Для чистоты эксперимента создал новый проект, и в StoryBoard во ViewController кинул Image View, туда картинку задал, а также размеры 200x200. И подключил его в коде. Собственно вот сам код контроллера:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testIMG: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testIMG.frame = CGRectMake(300, 150, 10, 10)
    }
}
```

Вроде бы размеры должны измениться, но при запуске приложения картинка остаётся того же самого размера. И какие бы размеры я не ставил в коде (хоть 100x100, хоть 10x10) всё бестолку, картинка остаётся 200x200.

Скажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте перенести свой код во viewDidAppear

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не помогло. Я даже попробовал вместо изменения размеров, сменить программно картинку: testIMG.image = UIImage(named: "foo"), но тоже никаких изменений - ни в viewDidLoad ни в viewDidAppear.

Comment: тогда у вашего viewController есть функция `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` вот в ней точно будет работать

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko всё равно не работает((

Comment: скиньте весь код, посмотрю

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не знаю правильно ли я запаковал. Вот: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29604742/temp/test2.zip

Comment: у вас картинка в jpg. для него вы должны указывать расширение. короче вместо `testIMG.image = UIImage(named: "foo")` должно быть `testIMG.image = UIImage(named: "foo.jpg")`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да, теперь сработало. Работает только в viewDidLayoutSubviews. А будет ли это работать в таблице? К примеру, у меня таблица, куда выводятся посты. И вот у меня там в каждой ячейки выводится аватарка, ник автора поста и контент (Label). Всё это в сториборде размечено и привязано при помощи констрейнтов. Будет ли работать изменение размера там? Или это только в viewDidLayoutSubviews работает? Я пробовал менять размеры аватарки таким образом, но не вышло. Я задавал размеры в tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: я бы сказал, что ваш подход не эффективен - либо делайте все в storyboard и использованием constraints, либо делайте все программно. Как вы видите такие гибриды, где половина тут, половина там не очень хороший подход.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да, я тоже пришёл к выводу, что надо программно добавлять ImageView. Сейчас разбираюсь с этим. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй убрать константные размеры в `Main.storyboard`. Вместо размеров поставь `bottom` и `top constraints`.

Или создайте `UIImageView` из кода, а не с storyboard.

Comment: Не совсем понял о чём вы. Как убрать константные размеры? Если удалить размеры, то там получаются просто 0x0. А если поставить констрейнты для верха и низа, то оно просто растягивается на всю высоту экрана.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Да, из кода создавать UIImageView получается. А также задаю высоту UIView (в который добавляются картинки) при помощи NSLayoutConstraint параметром .Height

Answer (score 1):

В interface builder у `UIImageView` который ты добавляешь, выставь атрибут `mode` как `aspect fit` возможно поможет.
А еще прочти эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/235181/)

Comment: Есть еще вероятность что ты констрейнты криво выставил, поэтому не изменяется размер

Comment: Не aspect fit не помогает. Я пошёл другим путём. Во-первых теперь создаю UIImageView из кода и добавляю в заранее заготовленную UIView. Во-вторых я использую констрейнт с параметром .Height для того, чтобы задать высоту моего view. Теперь всё работает.